# best algorithm to find aike blobs series

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, opencv

I want to find alike blobs (almost of the same size and on the same line).
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hJB5.png) is a sample image.

I'm using c# and opencv.

Comment: Will all the blobs be rectangular? If, so, just iterate through the image, find all the rectangles, and then use whatever criteria you want for "alike".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest doing a [Blob detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) and determine the center of gravity and the area of the blob. I am assuming that the rectangels in the image would be filled with black? If not then this step has to put before the blob extraction. With this coordinates you can calculate the difference between the points and a line. By moving the line in the image you get different "error". See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) how to calculate this error (just one example)

When [minimizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) this error, then you have you line.

To calculate the error you might also consider first to filter the blob coordinates by the size of the blobs (only about the same size)

Comment: This is a nice approach. I would suggest a variant: project the candidate blobs onto a line perpendicular to the test line. Then the projections would need to overlap sufficiently for the blobs to be considered "in a line". (This could even be done as a test of hypothesis that the blobs are from a single distribution, if statistical techniques are appropriate to the problem.) This would do something a bit different than your last suggestion of filtering by blob size, although it's also a way of dealing with varying blob sizes.

Comment: Ted: This would be a type of "Blob-Density function" projected onto the line, or? I like it.

Comment: I was thinking that it would be a density projected onto the subspace _orthogonal_ to the line.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, if only same size and lying on the same line (approximately) are the criteria then here's another way of going about it.

1. Find connected components (guess you could loosely call that blob detecting, not sure) using the OpenCV function cvFindContours(). [This](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/263221_connected-components-using-opencv) link provides working code to do that.
2. Compute the [Bounding Rectangle](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) of each contour as you step through the list of all contours present in the picture.
3. The Bounding Rectangle is essentially a [CvRect](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html?highlight=cvrect#cvsize) struct containing the x-position, y-position, width and height of the smallest rectangle that encloses the selected contour/feature.
   `typedef struct CvRect
   {
   int x;
   int y;
   int width;
   int height;
   }
   CvRect;`
4. Naturally for your picture I'd compare the y-positions of the contours are select the ones that are close.
5. Additionally the width and height fields in the structure will tell you about the similarity in size.

Note: same area may not always indicate same size. eg. a*b=ab, also (a/4)*(4b)=ab but hardly of same size. Code samples are in C but I think figuring it out in C# won't be too hard. Hope this works for you!